# How to apply text shadow to UITextView?

Tags: ios, iphone, uitextview

Actually I love `UILabel`. They're sweet. Now I had to go to `UITextView` because `UILabel` is not aligning text vertically to the top. Damn. One thing I really need is a text shadow. `UILabel` has it. `UITextView` seems to not have it. But I guess that guy just uses the same underlying `UIKit` `NSString` additions?? Maybe someone already has a solution for that problem? What would I overwrite?

Comment: i think you should accept adjwilli answer, because it's easy ant i think the most will agree that it's the right way to do it.

Answer (score 156):

```
text.layer.shadowColor = [[UIColor whiteColor] CGColor];
text.layer.shadowOffset = CGSizeMake(1.0f, 1.0f);
text.layer.shadowOpacity = 1.0f;
text.layer.shadowRadius = 1.0f;
```

And don't forget to add up top:

```
#import <QuartzCore/QuartzCore.h>
```

Comment: The answer marked correct will work I suppose but its messy and generally poor form.

Comment: I wish I could mark this up further -- this is the appropriate way to add a shadow to a UITextView.  The other method is very heavy handed and not at all the way that should be done for anything other than very trivial uses of UITextView.

Comment: weird behaviour: this approach adds shadow to the text itself, not to the uitextview box. I would like to add shadow to the box not to the text.

Comment: This works perfectly, kindly mark this as an alternative answer :)

Comment: text.layer.masksToBounds = NO; is needed also

Comment: Just used the exact code in adjwilli's answer and it worked perfectly without any need for anything else. THANK YOU, man.

Comment: textView's background needs to be set as clearColor in order for this to work

Answer (score 16):

The answer with

> text.layer.shadowColor

adds shadow to whole textView, perhaps it works, but it adds shadow not only to text.

The correct answer is:

```
CALayer *textLayer = ((CALayer *)[textView.layer.sublayers objectAtIndex:0]);
textLayer.shadowColor = [UIColor whiteColor].CGColor;
textLayer.shadowOffset = CGSizeMake(0.0f, 1.0f);
textLayer.shadowOpacity = 1.0f;
textLayer.shadowRadius = 1.0f;
```

Answer (score 13):

**Swift 3**

---

```
let textView = UITextView(frame: view.frame)
textView.font = UIFont(name: "Helvetica", size: 64.0)
textView.textColor = .red
textView.text = "Hello World"

textView.layer.shadowColor = UIColor.black.cgColor
textView.layer.shadowOffset = CGSize(width: 2.0, height: 2.0)
textView.layer.shadowOpacity = 1.0
textView.layer.shadowRadius = 2.0
textView.layer.backgroundColor = UIColor.clear.cgColor
```

---

**Swift 2.3**

---

```
let textView = UITextView(frame: view.frame)
textView.font = UIFont(name: "Helvetica", size: 64.0)
textView.textColor = UIColor.redColor()
textView.text = "Hello World"    

textView.layer.shadowColor = UIColor.blackColor().CGColor
textView.layer.shadowOffset = CGSize(width: 2.0, height: 2.0)
textView.layer.shadowOpacity = 1.0
textView.layer.shadowRadius = 2.0
textView.layer.backgroundColor = UIColor.clearColor().CGColor
```

Answer (score 12):

[image]

This **Swift example** uses the attributed string method of adding shadow to text. See [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/32269975/3681880) for more about attributed strings in Swift. This method (as opposed to using the [layer method](https://stackoverflow.com/a/27210233/3681880)) gives you the flexibility to set the shadow on a range of text if you want to.

```
// Create a string
let myString = "Shadow"

// Create a shadow
let myShadow = NSShadow()
myShadow.shadowBlurRadius = 3
myShadow.shadowOffset = CGSize(width: 3, height: 3)
myShadow.shadowColor = UIColor.gray

// Create an attribute from the shadow
let myAttribute = [ NSAttributedStringKey.shadow: myShadow ]

// Add the attribute to the string
let myAttrString = NSAttributedString(string: myString, attributes: myAttribute)

// set the attributed text on a label
myLabel.attributedText = myAttrString // can also use with UITextView
```

*Updated for Swift 4*

Answer (score 9):

In iOS 6+ use attributed text

```
NSShadow * shadow = [[NSShadow alloc] init];
shadow.shadowColor = [UIColor blackColor];
shadow.shadowOffset = CGSizeMake(2, 2);

NSDictionary * textAttributes =
@{ NSForegroundColorAttributeName : [UIColor blueColor],
   NSShadowAttributeName          : shadow,
   NSFontAttributeName            : [UIFont boldSystemFontOfSize:20] };

textView.attributedText = [[NSAttributedString alloc] initWithString:@"Hello" 
                                                          attributes:textAttributes];
```

[image: Hello example]

Answer (score 0):

It depends on the version of iOS you are using. Beginning with iOS 6 there is a single shadow supported, you set that as an attribute on an NSAttributedString that you then set onthe label.

Answer (score -1):

**swift 4, swift 4.2, swift 5 and above 
Simple and elegant solution , can use from interface builder easily**

```
extension UIView {
    /* The color of the shadow. Defaults to opaque black. Colors created
     * from patterns are currently NOT supported. Animatable. */
    @IBInspectable var shadowColor: UIColor? {
        set {
            layer.shadowColor = newValue!.cgColor
        }
        get {
            if let color = layer.shadowColor {
                return UIColor(cgColor: color)
            }
            else {
                return nil
            }
        }
    }

    /* The opacity of the shadow. Defaults to 0.4 Specifying a value outside the
     * [0,1] range will give undefined results. Animatable. */
    @IBInspectable var shadowOpacity: Float {
        set {
            layer.shadowOpacity = newValue
        }
        get {
            return layer.shadowOpacity
        }
    }

    /* The shadow offset. Defaults to (1, 2). Animatable. */
    @IBInspectable var shadowOffset: CGPoint {
        set {
            layer.shadowOffset = CGSize(width: newValue.x, height: newValue.y)
        }
        get {
            return CGPoint(x: layer.shadowOffset.width, y:layer.shadowOffset.height)
        }
    }

    /* The blur radius used to create the shadow. Defaults to 3. Animatable. */
    @IBInspectable var shadowRadius: CGFloat {
        set {
            layer.shadowRadius = newValue
        }
        get {
            return layer.shadowRadius
        }
    }
}
```