# UITextField shadow won't show

Tags: ios, swift, swift3

In my xib file, I have created a generic function through which I wanted to add a bottom border through implementing a shadow to those textfields

```
func setupTextField(textField: UITextField) {

        textField.leftViewMode = UITextFieldViewMode.always
        let imageView = UIImageView();
        let image = UIImage(named: "calendar");
        imageView.image = image;
        imageView.frame = CGRect(x: 5, y: 8, width: 20, height: 20)
        textField.addSubview(imageView)
        let paddingView = UIView(frame: CGRect(x: 0, y: 0, width: 40, height: textField.frame.height))
        textField.leftView = paddingView


        textField.borderStyle = .none
        textField.layer.backgroundColor = UIColor.white.cgColor
        textField.layer.masksToBounds = false
        textField.layer.shadowColor = UIColor(hex: "#D8D8D8").cgColor
        textField.layer.shadowOffset = CGSize(width: 0.0, height: 1.0)
        textField.layer.shadowOpacity = 1.0
        textField.layer.shadowRadius = 0.0


    }
```

And I have called this function from my `awakeFromNib()` method and as a result it added the shadow on my 2nd `UITextField` but not at the 1st one. Though from debug I can see that if there is no 2nd `UITextField` then this would draw a shadow on my 1st one.

How to overcome this problem?

Comment: Show the code where you have called this function.

Comment: Use: `textField.clipsToBounds = false`

Comment: i did that but didn't work @shallowThought

Comment: You need to set the background color to clear

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2851248/how-to-apply-text-shadow-to-uitextview/27210233?s=1|1.5888#27210233

Comment: actually it didn't work!! i have tried it @LeoDabus

Answer (score 0):

**For swift 4, swift 4.2, swift 5 Please refer below answer**
Can give shadow to any UIView sub classes(imageview, label, textfield, textview etc)

```
extension UIView {
    /* The color of the shadow. Defaults to opaque black. Colors created
     * from patterns are currently NOT supported. Animatable. */
    @IBInspectable var shadowColor: UIColor? {
        set {
            layer.shadowColor = newValue!.cgColor
        }
        get {
            if let color = layer.shadowColor {
                return UIColor(cgColor: color)
            }
            else {
                return nil
            }
        }
    }

    /* The opacity of the shadow. Defaults to 0.4 Specifying a value outside the
     * [0,1] range will give undefined results. Animatable. */
    @IBInspectable var shadowOpacity: Float {
        set {
            layer.shadowOpacity = newValue
        }
        get {
            return layer.shadowOpacity
        }
    }

    /* The shadow offset. Defaults to (1, 2). Animatable. */
    @IBInspectable var shadowOffset: CGPoint {
        set {
            layer.shadowOffset = CGSize(width: newValue.x, height: newValue.y)
        }
        get {
            return CGPoint(x: layer.shadowOffset.width, y:layer.shadowOffset.height)
        }
    }

    /* The blur radius used to create the shadow. Defaults to 3. Animatable. */
    @IBInspectable var shadowRadius: CGFloat {
        set {
            layer.shadowRadius = newValue
        }
        get {
            return layer.shadowRadius
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score -1):

Textfield shadow
swift 4.2

```
textFieldDOB.backgroundColor = UIColor.white            textFieldDOB.clipsToBounds = false
textFieldDOB.layer.shadowColor = UIColor.black.cgColor
textFieldDOB.layer.shadowOffset = CGSize.zero
textFieldDOB.layer.shadowOpacity = 0.3
textFieldDOB.layer.shadowRadius = 6
textFieldDOB.borderStyle = .none
```

Comment: TextFiled does not have a "borderStye" property, and this code does not work even with that removed.